# How to validate section in multi step form?

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-hook-form

I have a wizard form with the structure:

```
{
  contactInfo:{
    name: "string",
    email: "string",
    ...
  }
  petInfo: {
    petName: "string",
    petBreed: "string,
    ...
  }
  vetInfo: {
    vetName: "string",
    vetPhone: "string",
    ...
  }
}
```

At the top level of the component I render each section:

```
// Form Validation
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import schema from "utils/FormValidation/wizardFormValidation";
import { defaultValues } from "utils/FormValidation/packFormValidation";

function getSteps(): string[] {
  return ["Contact", "Emergency", "Pack", "Vet"];
}

function getStepContent(stepIndex: number): JSX.Element {
  switch (stepIndex) {
    case 0:
      return <Contact />;
    case 1:
      return <Emergency />;
    case 2:
      return <Pack />;
    case 3:
      return <Vet />;
    default:
      return null;
  }
}

function Welcome(): JSX.Element {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const petParent = useAppSelector(selectPetParent);
  const pack = useAppSelector(selectPack);
  const wizard = useAppSelector((state) => state.forms.wizard);
  const values = {
    ...petParent,
    pack: pack.length !== 0 ? [...pack] : [...defaultValues],
  } as Wizard;
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState<number>(0);
  const steps = getSteps();
  const isLastStep: boolean = activeStep === steps.length - 1;

  const handleNext = () => setActiveStep(activeStep + 1);
  const handleBack = () => setActiveStep(activeStep - 1);

  const methods = useForm({
    mode: "all",
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    defaultValues: {
      ...wizard,
    },
    values: values,
  });

  const onSubmit = () => {
    const formValues: Wizard = methods.getValues() as unknown as Wizard;
    dispatch(submitWizardForm(formValues)).unwrap();
  };

  const handleDisabled = (): boolean => {
    let section: any;
    switch (activeStep) {
      case 0:
        section = "contactInfo";
        break;
      case 1:
        section = "eContacts";
        break;
      case 2:
        section = "pack";
        break;
      case 3:
        section = "vetInfo";
        break;
    }
    const fieldState = methods.getFieldState(section, methods.formState);
    return activeStep !== 3 ? fieldState.invalid : !methods.formState.isValid;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = methods.watch((value, { name, type }) => {
      dispatch(updateWizardForm(value));
    });
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, [methods.watch]);

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <div role="form" onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div>{getStepContent(activeStep)}</div>
        {activeStep === 0 ? (
          <div></div>
        ) : (
          <button onClick={handleBack}>back</button>
        )}

        <button
          disabled={handleDisabled()}
          onClick={!isLastStep ? handleNext : onSubmit}
        >
          {isLastStep ? "submit" : "next"}
        </button>
      </div>
    </FormProvider>
  );
}

export default Welcome;
```

This issue I'm having is determining whether each section (contactInfo, petInfo, vetInfo) `isValid` in order to properly handle whether to disable the `next` button. At the moment `handleDisabled` checks to see if the section is `fieldState.invalid` but this doesn't always return false if the section of the form is blank. I tried checking the section `fieldState.isTouched` and `fieldState.isDirty` but those don't check for each field in the section just the section as a whole. Meaning if a user touches/dirties a single field in the section `isTouched`/`isDirty` return true and `getFieldState.invalid` returns false which leads to users not knowing which fields they need to complete.

The methods on `formState` are ideal but they only work on the form as a whole. I want to check if a specific section `isValid`. Otherwise I would have to check each individual field using `getFieldState` in each section.

I have looked over the documentation but the only solution I see is to break up each section into a separate form and then use `formState.isValid` on each separate form section. Is there a way to keep the code as is and check `isValid` by section?

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to use `trigger()` to validate the entire form on `handleNext`

```
  const handleNext = async () => {
    let section: any;
    switch (activeStep) {
      case 0:
        section = "contactInfo";
        break;
      case 1:
        section = "eContacts";
        break;
      case 2:
        section = "pack";
        break;
      case 3:
        section = "vetInfo";
        break;
      default:
        section = "contactInfo";
    }
    const isStepValid = await trigger(section);
    if (isStepValid) setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };
```